# null value in column \"file_name\" violates not-null constraint

Tags: c

when I am trying create file in the remote and copy the conentent to th file at remote side uisng curl_mime_init(), host is giving reponse like** "null value in column "file_name" violates not-null constraint**"
file name is :c1235-7621-1673373808-A.WAV
and find the below code which i tried .

```
 char CloudIdBuf[200] = {0};
 curl_mime *form = NULL;
 curl_mimepart *field = NULL;
 struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;
 static const char buf[] = "Expect:";
 char postBuffer[60] = {0};
 curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
 curl = curl_easy_init();
 if(curl) 
 {
 /* Create the form */
 form = curl_mime_init(curl);
 /* Fill in the file upload field */
  field = curl_mime_addpart(form);
 curl_mime_name(field, "sendfile");
 curl_mime_filedata(field, abPtr);   //File cnnetent in the abptr
 /* Fill in the filename field */
 field = curl_mime_addpart(form);
  curl_mime_name(field, "filename");
 curl_mime_data(field, fileName, CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
 curl_mime_data(field, "c1235-7621-1673373808-A.WAV", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED); filename within ""

 /* Fill in the submit field too, even if this is rarely needed */
 field = curl_mime_addpart(form);
 curl_mime_name(field, "submit");
 curl_mime_data(field, "send", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

 /* initialize custom header list (stating that Expect: 100-continue is not
   wanted */
 headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);
 /* what URL that receives this POST */
         
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,CloudIdBuf); 
  /* only disable 100-continue header if explicitly requested */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, form);
  curl_easy_setopt( curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

/* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
/* Check for errors */
if(res != CURLE_OK)
  fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
          curl_easy_strerror(res));

/* then cleanup the form */
curl_mime_free(form);
/* free slist */
curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);
}
```

please mention anything wrong in the parameter setting in Curl_mime function or in the filename

Thanks in Advance